# I cannot instantiate an object of class Integer in my code (Java)

Tags: java, class, generics

I am creating a class, Doubly Linked List with ListNode as innerclass.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Integer> {

    /** Return a representation of this list: its values, with adjacent
     * ones separated by ", ", "[" at the beginning, and "]" at the end. <br>
     * 
     * E.g. for the list containing 6 3 8 in that order, return "[6, 3, 8]". */
    public String toString() {
        String s;

        ListNode i = new ListNode(null, null, *new Integer(0)*);
```

Why is it that I get the error, cannot instantiate the type `Integer`?

Comment: Show us the definition of the `ListNode` class.

Answer (score 11):

The `Integer` in your class definition is generic type parameter which hides the `Integer` wrapper class.

So, `new Integer(0)` you use inside the class is taking `Integer` as type parameter, and not the `Integer` type itself. Since, for a type parameter `T`, you can't just do - `new T();`, because the type is generic in that class. Compiler doesn't know what type exactly it is. So, the code is not valid.

Try changing your class to:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    public String toString() {
        ListNode i = new ListNode(null, null, new Integer(0));
        return ...;
    }
}
```

it will work. But I suspect that you really want this. I guess you want to instantiate the type parameter inside your generic class. Well, that's not possible directly.

You pass the actual type argument while instantiating that class like this:

```
DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dLinkedList = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
```

**P.S:** It would be better if you explain your problem statement clearly, and put some more context into the question.

Comment: Most possible answer for the question :) +1.